# How can I remove all comments from a file?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have a file which includes comments:

```
foo
bar
stuff
#Do not show this...
morestuff
evenmorestuff#Or this
```

I want to print the file without including any of the comments:

```
foo
bar
stuff
morestuff
evenmorestuff
```

There are a lot of applications where this would be helpful.  What is a good way to do it?

Comment: you cannot remove parts of a line with grep. you can use sed for this

Comment: Your text and your example contradict. You write about lines being commented out, but clearly from the last line you mean line parts. And then the first line with a comment is deleted including EOL, and second second might be, but it is not clear as that is the last line. Please rephrase 'lines commented out' to be exact and disambiguate your examples.

Comment: try using  `awk -F\# '$1!="" { print $1 ;} '` .

Comment: @Anthon I edited it like you said... :)

Comment: @Questionmark what happens to the EOL after the comment on the last line? Can that be gobbled up? (Leaving the file ending in a line without a newline).

Comment: @Anthon Sure... That works

Comment: How would a line like `echo '#'  # output a #` be handled?

Comment: @Kusalananda  Interesting.  Hadn't thought about it.  According to all the answers that have been posted, I think we would end up with just `echo '`.  Do you have a clever way to handle those?

Comment: @Questionmark I might be clever, but I'm not writing-a-shell-grammar-parser clever.

Comment: @Archemar your awk answer is the BEST out of all the other answer here including the sed/grep/egrep etc.

Comment: @Devy thanks, this is but a dirty hack, it doesn't take into account kusalanada's comment. (and after 4 1/2 years I am not turning it to a answer)

Comment: @Archemar not turning it to an answer is fine. And 90% of the use cases here is to remove comment lines (not trailing comments) so that default config files are more concise and readable. I am sure a lot of readers would agree.

Comment: `grep -v '^#.*' filename` (Sorry, I can't submit my own answer.) (-v inverts the match, so it returns all rows that DON'T match a line starting with `#`.)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

One way to remove all comments is to use `grep` with `-o` option:

```
grep -o '^[^#]*' file
```

where

- `-o`: prints only matched **part** of the line
- first `^`: beginning of the line
- `[^#]*`: any character except `#` repeated zero or more times

Note that empty lines will be removed too, but lines with only spaces will stay.

Comment: I would use `grep -v '^#' file > newfilewithoutcomments`

Comment: It should be noted this is NOT a general method for shell scripts, as for example the line `somvar='I am a long complicated string ## with special characters' # and I am a comment` will not be handled correctly.

Comment: This variant works better for me (on a Mac): `grep -o '^[^#].*' file`

Comment: The comments are gone but I'm seeing a bunch of white space in their place in the output? `sed` solution only has one blank line, seems like a solid argument to use other answer, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @JBallin Did you define some alias for `grep` maybe? Try changing `grep` to `command grep`, if you still see spaces post the sample input.

Comment: @jimmij https://gist.github.com/JBallin/c89829846df419d7604384228a305d5a

Comment: @JBallin Cannot reproduce that, what version is it (`grep --version`)?

Comment: @jimmij looks like I'm using the Mac built-in (not 3+): grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

Comment: @JBallin I'm not sure why it behaves so weirdly on FreeBSD. You can try to add `-P` option (perl compatible mode), if it is available on your system.

Comment: @jimmij no dice.
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

Comment: How did this get 40 upvotes and become selected as the best answer???  It doesn't even handle the simple case `print "#tag"   # Print a hashtag.`.

Comment: Like most answers, this will even kill the shebang!

Comment: It is the wrong answer!

Comment: in case you want to include the bash shebang like ```#!/bin/bash```, use ```grep -v -P '^\s*#(?!!).*$'``` , here -v means exclude what grep match and -P means Perl regex which is more powerful.

Comment: This cannot work in-place like sed could

Answer (score 47):

I believe `sed` can do a much better job of this than `grep`. Something like this:

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*#/d;s/#.*//' your_file
```

**Explanation**

- `sed` will by default look at your file line by line and print each line after possibly applying the transformations in the quotes. (`sed '' your_file` will just print all the lines unchanged).
- Here we're giving `sed` two commands to perform on each line (they're separated by a semicolon).
- The first command says: `/^[[:blank:]]*#/d`. In English, that means if the line matches a hash at its beginning (preceded by any number of leading blanks), delete that line (it will not be printed).
- The second command is: `s/#.*//`. In English that is, substitute a hash mark followed by as many things as you can find (till the end of the line, that is) with nothing (nothing is the empty space between the final two `//`).
- In summary, this will run through your file deleting lines that consist entirely of comments and any lines left after that will have the comments stricken out of them.

Comment: It will also delete anything found after a hash *inside a string*, no ?  E.g. `mystring="Hello I am a #hash"`  will become  `mystring="Hello I am a"`

Comment: @javadba, yes, but at that point you might as well use a full parser.  What's going to be using this data that can understand quotes and variable assignments but *can't* handle comments?  (This is why many config files such as `crontab` only allow full-line comments, with or without leading whitespace, but do not allow trailing comments on a line.  The logic is MUCH simpler.  Use only the first of the two Sed instructions in this answer for a crontab comment stripper.)

Comment: great answer, this looks like a great balance of utility vs. complexity for a wide array of general use-cases,  but in the case that you know ahead of time that you only need to delete lines starting directly with `#` (in column 1), is there any benefit to `sed` over `grep -v "^#"` ?

Comment: Like most answers, this will even kill the shebang!

Comment: A small enhancement... `sed '/^[[:blank:]]*#/d;s/[[:blank:]]*#.*//' your_file`. Your original command leaves some trailing blanks in a line. My enhancement gets rid of those, too.

Answer (score 7):

As others have pointed out, sed and other text-based tools won't work well if any parts of a script look like comments but actually aren't. For example, you could find a # inside a string, or the rather common `$#` and `${#param}`.

I wrote a shell formatter called [shfmt](https://github.com/mvdan/sh), which has a feature to minify code. That includes removing comments, among other things:

```
$ cat foo.sh
echo $# # inline comment
# lone comment
echo '# this is not a comment'
[mvdan@carbon:12] [0] [/home/mvdan]
$ shfmt -mn foo.sh
echo $#
echo '# this is not a comment'
```

The parser and printer are Go packages, so if you'd like a custom solution, it should be fairly easy to write a 20-line Go program to remove comments in the exact way that you want.

Answer (score 6):

### Example input

```
cat example.sh
```

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# example script

echo "# test";# echo "# test"

# check the first parameter
if [ "$1" = "#" ]; then 
  # test couple of different cases
  echo "#"; # output # character 
  echo '\#'; # output # character '#' for test purpose
  echo \#\#\#; # comment # comment # comment '# comment'
  echo \#
  echo \#;
  echo \#; # comment
fi
# end of the script
```

### Remove comments

```bsh
sed -e '1{/^#!/ {p}}; /^[\t\ ]*#/d;/\.*#.*/ {/[\x22\x27].*#.*[\x22\x27]/ !{:regular_loop s/\(.*\)*[^\]#.*/\1/;t regular_loop}; /[\x22\x27].*#.*[\x22\x27]/ {:special_loop s/\([\x22\x27].*#.*[^\x22\x27]\)#.*/\1/;t special_loop}; /\\#/ {:second_special_loop s/\(.*\\#.*[^\]\)#.*/\1/;t second_special_loop}}' example.sh
```

### Result

```
cat example.sh
```

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

echo "# test";

if [ "$1" = "#" ]; then 
  echo "#"; 
  echo '\#'; 
  echo \#\#\#; 
  echo \#
  echo \#;
  echo \#;
fi
```

Read how it works at source: https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2012/11/07/how-to-remove-comments-from-a-shell-script/

Comment: That's the way to do it!

Comment: That's by far the best solution so far, but I even this fails on multi-line strings with hashes in them. 
echo  -e "this is \n#NOT# a comment"

I have no idea of how to solve that, though.

Comment: `sed: 1: "1{/^#!/ {p}}; /^[\t\ ]* ...": extra characters at the end of p command`

Comment: And actually, it's full of holes. It would cut `echo "#\"#"` as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the required output using sed command. The below command had done the trick for me.

```
sed 's/#.*$//g' FileName
```

Where

- `#.*$` - Regexp will filter all the string that starts with `#` up to the end of the line

Here we need to remove those lines so we replaced with empty so skipping 'replacement' part.

- `g` - mentioning repeated search of the pattern until end of file is reached.

General syntax of sed: `s/regexp/replacement/flags FileName`

Comment: note: 4th line replaced with new line in this case.

Comment: Try that with a script containing that `sed` command...

Comment: It won't handle `print "#tag" # Print a hashtag.`

Answer (score 2):

You can use invert match like this:

```bsh
grep -v "#" filename
```

`-v`
 Select lines not matching any of the specified patterns. (As [specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html).)

Comment: @alinh Thanks for reviewing the answer. Please note that the question required not only the beginning of the line but anywhere in the file. This is also showing in his/her expected result in the question above. My answer would be incorrect if I only look for beginning of the line.

Comment: zzz. my bad, didn't see the last line :(

Comment: This will completely remove the line starting with `evenmorestuff` in the OP's example.

Comment: @JosephR. good catch. I missed that earlier. In this case `grep -o '^[^#]*' file` would be the best solution. this is already explained by jimmij. thanks for your review

Comment: It won't handle `print "#tag" # Print a hashtag.`

Answer (score 2):

Use a command like:

```bsh
grep -E -v "^#|^$" <file-name>
```

- `-v` inverts the match, *i.e.* only outputs lines which do not match
- `^#` matches lines starting with `#`
- `^$` matches empty lines

Answer (score 1):

```
cat YOUR_FILE | cut -d'#' -f1
```

It uses `#` as column separator and keeps just the first column (that is everything before `#`).

Comment: If `YOUR_FILE` is a script containing those commands, the script would leave `cat YOUR_FILE | cut -'` in the file on that line.

Comment: It doesn't even handle the simple case `print "#tag" # Print a hashtag..`

Answer (score 1):

I like [Joseph R.'s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157619/86440) but needed it to strip `//` comments too, so I modified it slightly & tested on RHEL:

```bsh
# no comments alias
alias nocom="sed -E '/^[[:blank:]]*(\/\/|#)/d;s/#.*//' | strings"

# example
cat SomeFile | nocom | less
```

I bet there's a better way to remove blank lines than using strings but it was the quick & dirty solution I used.

Comment: It won't handle `print "#tag" # Print a hashtag.`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
sed -i.old -E  "/^(#.*)$/d" file
```

Comment: It won't handle `print "#tag" # Print a hashtag.`

Answer (score 1):

Following the 2nd answer of Joseph R., I add `/^$/d` to remove blank line.

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*#/d;s/#.*//;/^$/d'
```

Comment: This would screw your script if you're using something like: `EXTENSION="${FILENAME##*.}"` (it'll delete `##*.}`)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to use the command:

```bsh
sed -i.$(date +%F) '/^#/d;/^$/d' ntp.conf
```

The `-i` is the in-place edit but the prefix directly following tells sed to create a backup. In this case with a date extension (`ntp.conf.date`) We run two commands each with an address space, the first deletes the commented lines and the second, separated from the first by a semi-colon, deletes the blank lines.

I found this solution on : [theurbanpenguin.com](https://www.theurbanpenguin.com/lpic-1-103-2-using-sed/)

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers seem to do this justice, they either leave in empty lines, or leave in lines where the comment isn't at the first character. I ended up using this:

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.bashrc
alias nocom='sed -e "/^\s*#/d" -e "/^\s*$/d"'
EOF
```

This sets up an alias, so that you don't have to memorize it (which is impossible to begin with). Open a new session, and you'll have the new `nocom` command. Then you can just

```
nocom /etc/foobar.conf
```

Cheers.

Comment: It won't handle `print "#tag" # Print a hashtag.`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '!/^#/{gsub(/#.*/,"",$0);print}' filename
```

output

```
foo
bar
stuff
morestuff
evenmorestuff
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm posting what works for me and seems to make the most sense, after reading through the others, with explanation.  A couple of posts came close, but I could not comment yet (because I'm a newb):

```
grep -E -v "(^#.*|^$)" filename
```

- `-E` = interpret the following pattern as a regular expression, similar to using egrep
- `-v` = print the inversion of the pattern (lines that do not match the expression will be printed)
- `"(^#.*|^$)"` = this has a pipe which designates an OR statement. This expression says to print any line that starts with a `#` (and anything else after it) OR any line with zero characters between the beginning and end of the line.

The `-v` will print on the screen the inversion of that, which will be any line with characters that does not start with a `#`.

Comment: It won't handle `print "#tag" # Print a hashtag.`

Comment: Ah, right... of course.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I was looking for an answer with regards to typical linux configuration files, such as pam.d configs, so I didn't think of that.  I guess it would have to be adapted to find and remove any comments that lie on the same line as code.  I just saw probably a better solution to my particular issue above: egrep -v "#|$^"

Comment: @RayButterworth, but why it should look for anything that doesn't starts with `#` , when its explicit that to look for anything that starts-with `^#`, if  you want to do that that then better to use `egrep -v '^(#|"|$)'` .

Comment: @KarnKumar, the question explicitly says that `evenmorestuff#Or this` should be stripped to `evenmorestuff`.

Comment: @RayButterworth,  my bad just overlooked that :(,  then `sed 's/#.*$//;/^$/d'`  OR `sed -n  's/#.*//;/^$/!p'` this  should work.