# Using grep to remove comments from a file

Tags: grep, raspbian

I'm trying to use grep to remove the comments from a file, smb.conf to be specific, and bash is giving me an error.  I found this question [How to remove all comments from a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157328/how-to-remove-all-comments-from-a-file) that gives the syntax for grep to do this, but it doesn't overwrite the file, it just prints it to the terminal.  I would like to effectively overwrite the file.  This is what's going on:

```
 $ sudo grep -o '^[^#]*' /etc/samba/smb.conf >> /etc/samba/smb.conf
-bash: /etc/samba/smb.conf: Permission denied
```

I have done something like this before, but then I was following an online guide and I vaguely remember having to start up bash before I could grep.  Obviously, I can't find that guide again.

How do you use grep to strip out the comments from a file?

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi B+ running Raspbian Jessie.

Comment: you're getting the permissions error because the elevated sudo permissions only last until the `>>` redirection, at which point it is your user shell. redirect it to a file you can write to, then sudo mv it; or sudo vi the file and pipe its contents to the grep

Comment: In any case, reading and writing to the same file would not work as intended.  `sed` is a better approach (using `-i`)

Comment: If one of the 3 answers below worked for you, please accept one of them using the check-mark. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i -e 's/#.*$//' -e '/^$/d' inputFile
```

in addition to removing all comments, it removes empty lines as well. I know you asked it with grep, but I thought I'd suggest this one. Functionally it is the same or even better by removing empty lines, compacting the size of the file, which I am assuming is your target.

EDIT: yes replace `#` with `;` and you should be good. At least on my CentOS 6 box it worked. You might need to put a `\` in front of the `;` if it complains about a invalid character or something.

Comment: That worked.  If I want to remove some stuff commented out with an `;`, I just change the `#` in the above sed command?

Comment: Mel types faster than I do! The answer to your question is 'yes'

Comment: You would not need to escape the ; here, as we're inside quote marks. Only thing I'd suggest is that there's no need to $ anchor after a .*  The * is greedy and will gobble to EOL by itself.

Comment: Normally, I wouldn't escape either. As I indicated, the command works without any problem with either `#` or `;` as the comment delimeters, on my CentOS 6 server. But since user indicated his target platform is raspbian, I thought the shell interpretation might be different as I haven't had the pleasure of dealing with any RasPi server yet.

Answer (score 2):

sed is one option that can "directly" edit a file (by making a temporary copy of it). This command will tell sed to edit /etc/samba/smb.conf `-i` in place, and to `-n` not print lines by default.

```
sudo sed -i -n '/^[^#]/ p' /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

The lines we tell it to 'p' print are the ones that match your grep regex, which I modified only slightly to remove the extraneous trailing `*`. Here, the regex says "match lines that start with anything other than an [octothorpe](http://99percentinvisible.org/episode/octothorpe/)".

Comment: For anyone stumbling for a solution to remove # and ; from smb.conf: `sudo sed -i -n '/^[^#;]/ p' /etc/samba/smb.conf` does just that, or (safer) `sed -n '/^[^#]/ p' /etc/samba/smb.conf` to inspect before changes.

This is the only solution where the addition of ; as a comment character is clear and easy, or working at all.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern should be specific, to avoid deleting lines *containing* a '#':

```
sudo sed -r -i 's/^[[:space:]]*#.*$//' /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

The question did not actually ask to delete blank lines; this command leaves them (as well as blanked lines resulting from the substitution).

Like the other solutions, this relies on the `-i` option, which is non-standard (see [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)), as well as `-r` (also non-standard).  The use of the options depends on the [platform](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Invoking-sed), of course.

Comment: Nice addition of the (optional) leading space.

Comment: That's usually legal (a few things, such as terminfo, do not like leading blanks for comments).