# How to remove all comments from a javascript file using common Linux command line tools?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, regular-expression

I have a javascript file with deeply needed comments. Javascript uses C style comments:

```
//this is a single line comment
```

And

```
/* this is
a multi-line
comment */
```

However, the actual code looks closer to this:

```
/* blah blah
// [NOTE] blah blah
// blah
// blah blah blah
// blah
// blah blah
function("string", false);
// 1: blah blah blah blah blah blah
// [1] https://example.com
function("string", true);
/* blah blah
* blah blah //* /
function("string", false);
// * * * /
// 18: blah blah blah blah blah blah
// [-] (part1) https://example.org/43
function("string", 0);
// * * * /
// 20: blah blah blah blah blah blah
// [NOTE] blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
// [-] https://example.org/62015
function("some_string", "string"); // (comment)
// 0301: blah blah blah blah blah blah
// [-] https://example.org/205
// function("string", false);
// 040: blah blah blah blah blah blah
// What is this?
// [-] https://example.org/58917
function("string", true);
// 050: blah blah blah blah blah blah
// [-] https://example.org/57226
function("string", false);
// 103: blah blah blah blah blah blah
// [-] https://example.org/53751
// function("string", false);
// 203: blah blah blah blah blah blah
// [WARNING] This may break
// [-] https://example.org/70082
function("string", false);
// 27: blah blah blah blah blah blah
// [-] https://example.org/57170
// function("string", 90); // default: 90
// 55: blah blah blah blah blah blah
// [-] https://example.org/73595
// function("string", true);
// * * * /
// ***/
function("string", 99); //comment comment
```

The answers I found, like this one, deal with simpler situations.

shell script - How can I remove all comments from a file? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange [How can I remove all comments from a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157328/how-can-i-remove-all-comments-from-a-file)

The main problem I experienced was that my various regex were too greedy, for example, selecting everything from the very first `/*` to the very last `*/`. I did not try Perl because I'm not familiar with it. And, unfortunately, the tools I did try did not have support for all the regex syntax I would have wanted to try. I'm not sure which simple tool is best suited for this task.

Comment: Regular expressions cannot parse out comments in that format because it does not represent a regular language. Non-regular regexps (like Perl's) might have a chance.

Comment: Is this a specific or general problem? In the specific, some variant of minify | prettify is probably good enough (that is, using actual JavaScript parsers).

Comment: I'm guessing the comments don't always start at the beginning of the line, right? Related: https://j11y.io/javascript/removing-comments-in-javascript/

Comment: This is a specific problem. Following the advice suggested in the comments, I used this approach to solve my specific problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2394040/463994

Comment: Complex example still lacks cases like `function("string //")`.

Comment: This is *practically* not achievable neither in any regular expression tool nor in perl. To do this reliably you would need to re-write good part of the javascript interpreter to take care of its syntax. Of course *theoretically* you can do that, but it is a huge task and not worth the effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `cpp -undef -P your_file.js` or `cc -undef -E -P -xc your_file.js` for that.

If you don't think `cpp` or `cc` are "common" enough tools, tough luck. They really should be.

Comment: I used gcc, as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2394040/463994

Comment: Yes, you should use the `-undef ` or `-fpreprocessed` options to inhibit macros; thanks for the heads-up.