# Syntax highlighting combinations of strings and comments in nano

Tags: regular-expression, nano, syntax-highlighting

I was wondering if anyone could tell me if it possible to configure syntax highlighting in `.nanorc` so that in the following text ...

```
Dim s$ = "foo ' bar" ' bar "foo"
```

... the string `"foo 'bar"` is all highlighted one colour and the trailing comment `' bar "foo"` is highlighted another.

If I do this:

```
# Comments.
color yellow "'.*"

# Strings
color brightmagenta ""(\\.|[^"])*""
```

Then I get this:

[image: Image1]

And if I do it in the other order:

```
# Strings
color brightmagenta ""(\\.|[^"])*""

# Comments.
color yellow "'.*"
```

Then I get this:

[image: Image2]

Comment: See [Feature Request: Resource file for Visual Basic #382](https://github.com/scopatz/nanorc/issues/382)

Answer (score 1):

If the comment does **not** contain a `'`, that is to say that the *last* `'` in the line is the beginning of any comment then it would seem to be best to work *backwards* from the end of the line, with a non-greedy search.

Try this, which uses your strings term but with a different comments term:

```
# Strings
color brightmagenta ""(\\.|[^"])*""

# Comments.
color green "[^']*$"
```

This works, ***except*** that the comment mark (`'`) is not coloured, unfortunately:

[image: Screenshot of almost the desired result]

Adding in an additional `'`, like so:

```
# Strings
color brightmagenta ""(\\.|[^"])*""

# Comments.
color green "'[^']*$"
```

finally gives the desired result:

[image: Screenshot of the desired result]

Note: The alternative to the non-greedy [`[^']*`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1103159/4424636) is `'.*?`, which is what I *first* tried to use, see below, but it failed...

---

#### Lazy (non-greedy) `*?` causes an error

My first thought was to use `.*?`, which *would* also colour the comment marker (`'`), like so:

```
# Comments.

color green "'.*?$"
```

Logically, this non-greedy search from the end should also work for your comments.

However, nano throws an error:

```
Bad regex "'.*?$": repetition-operator operand invalid
```

It *might* be a bug, see [Bad regex in php.nanorc, sh.nanorc & zsh.nanorc using nano 2.3.6 on Mac OS X from brew #41](https://github.com/scopatz/nanorc/issues/41) which was supposedly fixed:

> Answer: POSIX regex doesn't support ? for laziness (or laziness at all). Removing the ?s from the offending lines got rid of the errors, but you may not want to do that here since it will change evaluation for everyone else.

Note: I got this error when running nano on OS X - I'm not sure if that is relevant.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it just seems to add a different problem - i.e. the non-highlighted `'` and the incorrect handling if the comment itself contains a `'` character; it gets even worse if you want to handle REM comments at the same time (yes, this is BASIC). The other option, `'.*?$` doesn't report an error in Nano 4.8, but seems to behave exactly like `'.*`

Comment: But the comment  marker`'` *is* highlighted in green in the second example. As for the `'` in a comment, it is *totally* doable: See [Remove comments from file while ignoring quoted comment signs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/608099/97255) and [How can I remove all comments from a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/157328/97255)... I just haven't quite finished yet figuring it out. The `REM` would be possible too, with a little extra work (but neither were mentioned in your question). Ah, just realised that I am using nano 2.0.6, so that probably explains why I keep on getting errors.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and sorry for going dark. I think my initial comment may have been response to the suggestion from the original version of your post and not the later edit. Your `color green "'[^']*$"` does work except it introduces the alternative problem of the highlighting misbehaving if the comment contains a `'` character - which I didn't mention in my original question because it wasn't an issue with my own attempts. Likewise I didn't mention REM in my initial question because it is a lesser use-case and doesn't matter `'` can't be handled correctly.

Comment: No worries. I'll see if I can get a later version of `nano` and try to get the `*?` to work - I think it should do, looking at the other `.rcsc` files for nano, which seem to use it (IIRC).